# Multiple apache reverse proxies behind 1 external IP

Tags: high-availability

I have honestly tried searching on this topic, but I keep landing on articles explaining how to load balance web servers *behind* proxies, which is not what I want to do.

My setup is like this:

> WWW ---> Cisco ASA Firewall ----> Network Routers etc ----> Reverse Proxy (Apache) Server ----> Many Apache web servers

I want to include an additional Reverse Proxy Server, so that if it crashes (for whatever reason), the secondary one will take over (or take the full load if it's sharing the load)

I'm not sure where this "technology" will sit.

Obviously I need to add the extra Apache reverse proxy server, but what next?

Is it something I should be doing on the Cisco ASA firewall? As in, I tell it to somehow check the health on the two IP addresses of the RProxy servers and send packets to the live ones?

Is it a NAT rule, where I tell the ASA to NAT the outside public IP (which our websites sit on) to the two internal IP addresses of the RProxy servers? (But how will NAT know if one is dead?)

Which is the approach or method I should be looking at to achieve my goal?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the ASA to know if it can do failover for or load balancing over all active Apache reverse proxies. If not: then in general you set up a "floating" or "virtual" ip-address that you use as THE ip-address of your service. You point the NAT rules on your ASA to that floating ip-address. Both your Apache reverse proxy servers will join in a HA cluster that will move that floating ip-address from the active server to the back-up in case of maintenance or failure on the active server. [Keepalived](http://www.keepalived.org/) is common product to manage such a setup.

Comment: @HBrujin Thank you for your comment. I have found  a guide at https://www.howtoforge.com/high_availability_loadbalanced_apache_cluster which seems to cover this (but not using the firewall). It appears that I need something called UltraMonkey. I am experimenting now.

Comment: @HBrujin UltraMonkey seems to do a lot of hacking of the kernel, which I'm weary of. Do you know if your suggestion of keepalived is the more preferred solution? I guess, from their descriptions, that they serve very similar functions.

Comment: Why not using HAproxy OR LVS?
https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_16.04&p=lvs&f=1
http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/

OR
Something like this? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-highly-available-haproxy-servers-with-keepalived-and-floating-ips-on-ubuntu-14-04

All you really need is to configure Linux Virtual Server with Keepalived module.

https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_16.04&p=lvs&f=2